# How to change status occupying redux in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

You needed to change a variable, but this variable is in the store so I share the data

Data

```
export const lists =[
    {
    "id":1,
   "listname":"2022-09-09 00:00:00",
   "products":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "idlist":1,
         "product":"milk",
         "quantity":1,
         "measure":"liter",
         "status":false
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "idlist":1,
         "product":"bread",
         "quantity":1,
         "measure":"Kg",
         "status":false
      },
  ]},
]
```

the data I want to change is status

I came up with this idea in the reduce, in the action the action is defined

```
case CHANGE_PRODUCT_STATUS:
       const newList = state.lists.products.findIndex(
         (product) => product.id === action.productId
       );
       if (newList === -1) return state;
       return {
         ...state,
         lists: state.lists.products[newList].status = !state.lists.products[newList].status,
       };
```

it gives me an error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.lists.proucts.findIndex')

how can i fix it thanks

Comment: If the error message is really state.lists.proucts.findIndex you should add the missing ‚d‘ in proucts

Comment: I don't understand you, that the 'd', will be id ???

Comment: what you wrote as error message `error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.lists.proucts.findIndex')`, you are missing `d` in `products` in `state.lists.proucts.findIndex`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `lists.products` since `lists` is an *array* with one element inside. `lists[someArrayIndexHere].products` should work.